# OLAP: Why should all foreign keys between fact and dimension tables be surrogate keys?

Tags: olap

I'm reading a Wikipedia article about [OLAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_analytical_processing) and [OLAP Fact Tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fact_table) and the article states

> All foreign keys between fact and dimension tables should be surrogate
>   keys, not reused keys from operational data.

But it doesn't state why.
So, why should

> All foreign keys between fact and dimension tables should be surrogate
>   keys, not reused keys from operational data.

?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the detailed explanation of what is a [Dimension Table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimension_table) from wikipedia:

It is recommended that the key field is a simple integer for the reason that key value is meaningless and is only used to be join fields between the fact and dimension tables.
The usage of surrogate dimension keys brings several advantages among:

- Performance - join processing is much more efficient if a single field surrogate key is used,
- Buffer from operational key management practices - prevents form situations when removed data rows might reappear when their natural keys might be reused or reassigned after a long period of dormancy,
- Mapping to integrate disparate sources,
- Handle unknown or not applicable connections,
- Track changes in dimension attribute values.

Answer (score 1):

Hard earned knowledge.

Keys from operational data may change format at any time. It's just easier this way.

This is like asking "Should I use SSN as a primary key for `users` table?". While you (theoretically) could, it's not a good idea.

I admit, though, that I don't really know what I am talking about. I just remembered our Oracle guys having very strong opinion on this matter. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I would never use an SSN as a primary key for any table.  This information requires a great deal of protection.  Using it as a PK would mean it would appear in other tables as the foreign key join.  Even an Employee ID that is unique to the company and is not otherwise compromising should not be used.  Surrogate keys work faster.  They allow the dimension to be set up as SCD Type 2.  Even if you think only type 1 is needed, something may change down the road.